# How to put a figure in a two column document to the bottom in one column?

Tags: floats, two-column, elsarticle

I am writing an article with two columns and want to move a figure to the bottom. This figure is not suposed to cover the two columns, it is just a one column figure that is why I do not use figure*. When I just use [b] the figure and every following figures move to the end of the document.
What can I do to solve this problem? Here is a very short MWE, but that is what leads to the problem, that all figures move to the end. When allowing to cover two columns thus using figure* the [b] option works.

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{plots/example-plot.png}
\caption{Example text.}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you, hope the information is enough, let me know if you need more.

Comment: Maybe I did not find what you mean in that thread, but I actually do not want to use figure* because I want my figure to be just in one column.

Comment: Sorry... dleting the comment... I read "the figure is supposed" and not "the figure is NOT supposed"... Please condider to give a real working example with some text too in order to be possible to repoduce your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:(You have to add option `!b` instead of `b`)

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{figure}[!b]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example text.}
\label{fig:examplea}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{figure}[!b]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Example text. 2}
\label{fig:exampleb}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cool, thank you very much, it works fine! And so easy...

Comment: Welcome @Tini.. and sorry that didn't read carefully your post in first read. Happy TeXing...